# Xrm.WebApi how to retrieve attribute

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am trying to retrieve the ID and name of a lookup field in the entity Organization.

```js
var fetchxml = `
                <fetch distinct='false' mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
                <entity name="categorization">
                <attribute name="categorizationid"/>
                <attribute name="name"/>
                <attribute name="category1"/>
                <attribute name="category2"/>
                <attribute name="category3"/>
                <order descending="false" attribute="ava_category1"/>
                <filter type="and">
                <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
                </filter>
                </entity>
                </fetch>`;

fetchxml = "?fetchXml=" + encodeURIComponent(fetchxml);

Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("categorization", fetchxml).then(
  function success(results) {
    var data = [];
    for (var r in results) {
      var category1text = results[r].attributes["category1"].name;
      var category1lookup = results[r]["category1"].id;

      if (results[r].attributes["category2"] != undefined) {
        category2text = results[r].attributes["category2"].name;
        var category2lookup = results[r].attributes["category2"].id;
      }

      var category3text = null;

      if (results[r].attributes["category3"] != undefined) {
        category3text = results[r].attributes["category3"].name;
        var category3lookup = results[r].attributes["category3"].id;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Why doesnt the part `results[r].attributes["category1"].name` run? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
webApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("categorization", fetchxml)
    .then(result => {
        var data = [];

        result.entities.forEach(e => {
            var category1text = e.category1.name;
            ... etc.
```

Some context: `for in` loops through the properties of an object. It returns string values. You can use `for of` to loop through an array. I personally prefer the `.forEach()` function with lambda expressions.

See [W3Schools - JavaScript for/in Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_forin.asp).

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use odata for building your request like that

`  var option = "?$select=categorizationid,name,_category1_value,_category2_value,_category3_value&$filter=statecode eq 0";
SDK.WEBAPI.retrieveMultipleRecords("categorization", option, function (results) {

```
                for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                    var Cat1LookupGuid = results.value[i]["_category1_value"];
                    var Cat1LookupName = results.value[i]["_category1_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                    
                     var Cat2LookupGuid = results.value[i]["_category2_value"];
                    var Cat2LookupName = results.value[i]["_category2_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                    
                    var Cat3LookupGuid = results.value[i]["_category3_value"];
                    var Cat3LookupName = results.value[i]["_category3_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];                  


                }
            
        }, function (error) {
            console.error("your error" + error.message);
        }, function () { }
        );
        
        `
```

This tool can help you so much to create your odata request
https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder